# What is a Good General Purpose Open Source IDE that is written natively for Windows?

Tags: php, ruby, ide

Sorry to ask such a general question as I'm sure a lot of questions have been asked before about IDE's... but I specifically have major problems running IDE's that are written in non-native languages for Windows (like Java), NetBeans gave me horrible performance and I just tried Aptana and got a similar issue...

I have a fast computer (8 GB memory) and its never slow for anything else so this isn't an issue with my computer, I'm running Windows 7

I would appreciate if anyone can help identify a good open source IDE that has support for a variety of language (at least PHP and Ruby) that runs natively on Windows.. I don't care to meddle around with fixing the performance of these other IDE's, I'd just prefer to find one that works right from the beginning.

Comment: Eclipse is open source: http://www.eclipse.org/ but it may not match some of your other requirements. A lot of people seem to like to use it on windows though.

Comment: I would suspect a problem with your machine, because I get decent performance in Eclipse, NetBeans etc. even on my slow-as-molasses 1.8GHz laptop. What's your processor speed, and what version of Java do you have installed?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why netbeans gave you such issues, I have it running on a 6 year old desktop with only 3 gigs of ram and in win xp.  I actually see worse performance in Fedora 13 64 bit on the same system, but that's only during the initial load up, afterwards its fine.  Are you loading a massive number of framework/lib files in the project? Have you checked that it is running correctly under Java?
I would troubleshoot netbeans a bit more before giving up on it, as more simple editors won't give you true IDE power.  That said, I do like notepad++ on windows for simple stuff.

Comment: I wonder why people are suggesting products that aren't IDEs when the question clearly asks only IDEs.

Comment: Because there aren't (m)any? I don't see the point of making a general-purpose open source IDE using MFC or something.

Comment: Aptana (which is basically Eclipse) runs pretty well for me at work on an old P4 with 4GB of RAM. It also runs quite well on my Phenom II X3 w/ 6GB of RAM. And I usually have Photoshop or Illustrator running in the background.

I don't think the issue is the IDE. What exactly is slow in Aptana on your computer? What other applications do you have running?

Comment: Its not an issue with my computer or other applications, as I am only running aptana... I do have a lot of libraries, etc but this shouldn't matter.. I had been using a trial version of Nusphere and it ran fine but I switched to aptana so I could use ruby in it too as I think nusphere it php only.... I don't really know what the issue is but I don't have the time to spend figuring it out and it seems to occur in both aptana and netbeans whereas every other piece of software I run on my machine runs just fine.

Comment: My guess is that it's a Java issue. I had a similar experience when I first tried Eclipse, but a few years later when I installed Aptana there weren't any problems. Are the UI elements just slow to respond (e.g. delay between clicking on a menu and it popping up) or are there other performance problems you're noticing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is pretty good on Windows. It's not exactly native, runs on XUL (like Firefox does) but it's pretty complete and simple to use for a free IDE.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, their website doesn't exactly make it obvious that there is a free version but I found it.. thanks, am downloading it now

Comment: Can't blame them for trying to sell something :)

Comment: Yeah this seems really good, just started using it and its the speed it should be, definitely recommend it to anyone who comes across this in the future that has a similar problem to what I had

Comment: XUL is just the interface language like WPF. It's similar to if an application used an embedded HTML rendering engine to render its UI in HTML. That doesn't mean the program doesn't have native support just because HTML isn't platform-specific. The program is still written in Win32 API and runs without an emulator or virtual machine.

Comment: @Rick. Glad you like it. One annoying trick, in a project:
Add Folder = add "virtual" folder, Add Live folder = add actual physical folder.
Enjoy

Comment: @Lèse majesté. Agreed. What i meant is that there is some degree of runtime interpretation for the UI. The core is definitely natively compiled. Xul is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

i would try notepad++. it's not a full-featured ide, but it supports huge amount of languages, is fast and is extendable

Comment: yeah I use that for some things but I need an IDE where you can open files within it more easily (where it has a built in file browser)

Comment: @Rick: Oh, if that's the problem, just download the Explorer plugin or the FTP Explorer (http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central). There are a  lot of interesting plugins. That said, code completion is pretty lame, which is the main reason why I use Netbeans (a bit slow, especially on startup, but not that bad) to code. I use Notepad++ to quickly edit files, but if I have to write something from scratch, Netbeans it is.
That said, I would also love to find a better IDE for PHP. Compared to VS, Netbeans is far behind.

Comment: I used Notepad++ but switched to Sublime Text. It does the same Notepad++ does (with the same benefits you described), only I found it with more capabilities (at least for Haskell). It's kinda free.. it costs money but you can evaluate it forever, and all it will do is bug you with one message-box per session to buy when you tell it to save your file (I usually press Ctrl+S endlessly until it pops up and close it so it won't annoy me later on).

Answer (score 2):

(If there's an emacs answer..)
If you have no problem investing some time into learning, (g)[Vim](http://www.vim.org/).

Not an IDE but with some plugins ... almost.
(If you prefer point'n'click adventures over quick command line access (to manage the repository for ex.) this might not be for you, but if you should master vim (the end boss is hard) you'll finish most of your tasks faster than the college with the fancy IDE..)

not really a 'natively for windows' match either, but it'll easily beat all those IDEs speed wise.

Comment: I've used vim in linux and can't see using this ever as I am going between multiple files all the time, this would make things much slower in my opinion

Comment: @Rick: you can switch between open buffers with `:e` and a partial filename (with tab completion), or keep a bunch of open tabs, or have a window containing filenames that you do `^W_F` on.  There are some modules that facilitate project management; check out the `project` module (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69) and `NERDTree` (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658).  I've not used either of them (I find that vim's builtin capabilities meet my needs) but they are quite popular modules.

Comment: I find moving between multiple files all the time in vim is actually much faster.  You just need to teach your fingers the commands to split into windows, jump between windows, open the file explorer, list recently edited files etc.

Comment: Whoops, make that `:b` rather than `:e`.

Comment: Since i think you have some white on black config file editing images in mind, a example gVim screenshot on a Win box: http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/107/tempgw.png

Answer (score 1):

emacs is a great general purpose editor, with almost unlimited features.

Comment: emacs isn't written 'natively for windows', right?

Comment: What does "written natively for windows" mean? Emacs can be compiled for Windows machines to offer native support. The Windows port is even written using Win32 API.

Comment: In this instance I take "natively for Windows" to mean it is compiled for Windows, not for a virtual machine environment like Java.  So emacs and gvim both satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Programmers Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) very much. It's simple and has a clean interface. It's not an IDE but you can configure it to do almost everything.